# Transforming One to Many to rows

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table structures:

**Users**

```
| id | name 
|----|------
| 1  | Pete 
| 2  | Jeff
| 3  | Bob
```

**Properties**

```
| user_id | key    | value
|---------|--------|------
| 1       | Age    | 24
| 1       | Gender | M
| 1       | City   | New York
| 2       | Age    | 26
| 2       | Gender | M
| 3       | Age    | 30
| 3       | Eyes   | Blue
```

Now I need to 'group' these values into a (mysql) table so that I later can filter / sort / ...

**Expected Result**

```
| Name | Age | Gender  | City     | Eyes
|------|-----|---------|----------|-------
| Pete | 24  | M       | New York |
| Jeff | 26  | M       |          |
| Bob  | 30  |         |          | Blue
```

The reason why it is stored this way, is that each user can define it's 'own' properties.

Currently I am creating / filtering / sorting this table in code, however I am wondering if this can be done with mysql - using mysql to filter / sort this last table would be very handy indeed.

Note however that the number of rows are pretty substantial (hundred thousands to millions).

My concrete question(s) would be the following:

- Are there any tools that mysql brings to ease these kind of tasks ? (Temporary tables perhaps ? How does that perform with large datasets)
- Are there other databases that make such operations more trivial (NoSql types like Elastic Search?)

I am looking for general tips/advice, guidelines or possible alternatives to solve this kind of data 'grouping'.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about tools that exist for the stuff you are trying, but I can surely provide you a following query which can help you out.

```
SELECT 
  u.name as 'Name', 
  j1.value as 'Age',
  j2.value as 'Gender'
  j3.value as 'City'
  j4.value as 'Eyes'
FROM
  Users u 
  LEFT JOIN Properties j1 ON (u.id = j1.user_id AND j1.key = 'Age')
  LEFT JOIN Properties j2 ON (u.id = j2.user_id AND j2.key = 'Gender')
  LEFT JOIN Properties j3 ON (u.id = j3.user_id AND j3.key = 'City')
  LEFT JOIN Properties j4 ON (u.id = j4.user_id AND j4.key = 'Eyes')
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Comment: This works for this concrete example, but considering the amount of rows / values this will not perform (and then I need to filter / sort this)